# Why is my webscraper not detecting any changes?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wanted to code a websraper with beautifulsoup4 and requests. It scrapes the data of specifc columns of a specific table on a specifc table. It scrapes it once, waits a certain amount of time, scrapes it again and then compares both "scrapes". If there is a difference, it prints `"something has changed"`, and if there isn't, it prints `"no changes"`

Here is the entire code:

```py
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://website.com"
website = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, "html.parser")


data = []
table = soup.find("table", class_="table table-bordered table-sm table-responsive")
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')[0]
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values

    cols2 = row.find_all('td')[1]
    cols2 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols2]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols2 if ele])  # Get rid of empty values

    cols3 = row.find_all('td')[2]
    cols3 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols3]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols3 if ele])  # Get rid of empty values

    cols4 = row.find_all('td')[3]
    cols4 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols4]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols4 if ele])

    cols5 = row.find_all('td')[5]
    cols5 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols5]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols5 if ele])


    print(cols, cols2, cols3, cols4, cols5)

time.sleep(600)

for row in rows:
    cols11 = row.find_all('td')[0]
    cols11 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols11]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols11 if ele])  # Get rid of empty values

    cols22 = row.find_all('td')[1]
    cols22 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols22]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols22 if ele])  # Get rid of empty values

    cols33 = row.find_all('td')[2]
    cols33 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols33]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols33 if ele])  # Get rid of empty values

    cols44 = row.find_all('td')[3]
    cols44 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols44]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols44 if ele])

    cols55 = row.find_all('td')[5]
    cols55 = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols55]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols55 if ele])


    print(cols11, cols22, cols33, cols44, cols55)


if(cols == cols11, cols2 == cols22, cols5 == cols55):
    print("no changes")
else:
    print("something has changed")
```

Problem is: It always says `"no changes"` even though I know that something had changed. How can fix this?

Comment: While it may be related but not the root of your issue, can you explain in your own words what logic you expect the condition `if(cols == cols11, cols2 == cols22, cols5 == cols55)` to apply? Relatedly, have you manually inspected the contents of these lists to ensure they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Ok, I'll try. ```cols``` and ```cols11``` etc. are the same column. ```colsX``` contains the data of the first scrape and ```colsXX``` contains the data of the second scrape. In the if condition, it compares the content of the "associated" columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what others have said, **you must make another GET request to the URL** after pausing for a while inorder to detect any changes in the data of the webpage.

What you are doing is:

1. Making a GET request to the URL
2. Create a `soup` object of the response.
3. Extracting the data from the `soup` and storing them in variables.
4. Pause for a while - `time.sleep(600)`
5. **Again extracting the same information from the same `soup` - *(which will always be equal)* without making any new GET request.**

So you need to add this code right after `time.sleep(600)` statement to get any modified data from webpage (if any).

```py
URL = "https://website.com"
website = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", class_="table table-bordered table-sm table-responsive")
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thank you a lot, you are a hero!

Answer (score 1):

While lists can be compared in this way, it's not clear how you reached the conclusion that you can use a comma `,` in place of a logical AND `&&` operator in your `if` condition.

What you're doing here by wrapping your conditions in parenthesis `()` and joining them with a comma `,` (inadvertently, it would seem) is creating a `tuple` structure; all non-empty `tuple`s evaluate to `True`. Thus, your script is continually hitting the logic branch you feel should only be entered if there are no changes between any of your data structures.

Instead, use the logical AND `&&` properly (and don't cast the truth values themselves into a tuple) as you seem to intend:

```
if cols == cols11 && cols2 == cols22 && cols5 == cols55:
    print("no changes")
else:
    print("something has changed")
```

---

Tangential to the core of your question, but your code would benefit from (a) naming your variables in a much more descriptive manner, and (b) using datatypes that better fit your use case as opposed to introducing a brand-new numbered variable for every index and unnecessarily duplicating code.

Comment: Changed it, thanks a lot!